# Setting two column values from Single Column using sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-server-2008-r2

Iam having a table with following details

```
ID    statusID  logTime
100238  1   2011-07-07 03:48:43.000
100238  2   2011-07-07 03:48:46.000
100238  1   2011-07-07 09:07:57.000
100238  2   2011-07-07 16:12:28.000
100238  1   2011-07-08 02:59:57.000
100238  2   2011-07-08 03:00:00.000
100238  1   2011-07-08 09:26:37.000
100238  2   2011-07-08 14:03:05.000
```

and the required output should be like

```
repID   ClockIn                    ClockOut
100238  2011-07-07 03:48:43.000    2011-07-07 03:48:46.000
100238  2011-07-07 09:07:57.000    2011-07-07 16:12:28.000
100238  2011-07-08 02:59:57.000    2011-07-08 03:00:00.000
100238  2011-07-08 09:26:37.000    2011-07-08 14:03:05.000
```

ie.. if the statusID is 1 then logtime has to be in ClockIn column and if the statusID is 2, logtime has to be in ClockOut column

I have used the query like

```
SELECT repID,
       ClockIn,
       ClockOut from
  (SELECT a.eventID, 
          a.repID, 
          a.logTime, 
          CASE WHEN a.statusID = 1 THEN a.logTime ELSE NULL END AS ClockIn, 
          CASE WHEN b.statusID = 2 THEN b.logTime ELSE NULL END AS ClockOut
   FROM tbl_ets_reptimelog a
   LEFT JOIN tbl_ets_reptimelog b ON a.repID = b.repID)c
```

and it results like

```
repID   ClockIn                     ClockOut
100238  2011-07-07 03:48:43.000     NULL
100238  2011-07-07 03:48:43.000     2011-07-07 03:48:46.000
100238  2011-07-07 09:07:57.000     NULL
100238  2011-07-07 09:07:57.000     2011-07-07 16:12:28.000
100238  2011-07-08 02:59:57.000     NULL
100238  2011-07-08 02:59:57.000     2011-07-08 03:00:00.000
100238  2011-07-08 09:26:37.000     NULL
100238  2011-07-08 09:26:37.000     2011-07-08 14:03:05.000
```

How to remove the extra row that appears with the NULL valu ein the ClockOut Column

Please help to get out of this problem......

Answer (score 0):

Just add a WHERE clause in outer query

```
select repID,ClockIn,ClockOut from(select a.eventID, a.repID, a.logTime, 
case when a.statusID = 1 then a.logTime else null end as ClockIn,  
case when b.statusID = 2 then b.logTime else null end as ClockOut from tbl_ets_reptimelog a 
left join tbl_ets_reptimelog b on a.repID = b.repID)c
WHERE ClockOut IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should return the result that you need:

```
SELECT
  t1.ID,
  t1.logTime check_in,
  CASE WHEN MIN(t2.logTime) < MIN(t3.logTime) OR MIN(t3.logTime) IS NULL
       THEN MIN(t2.logTime) END check_out
FROM
  Logs t1 LEFT JOIN Logs t2
  ON t1.ID = t2.ID
     AND t2.statusID=2
     AND t1.logTime<t2.logTime
  LEFT JOIN Logs t3
  ON t2.ID = t3.ID
     AND t3.statusID=1
     AND t1.logTime<t3.logTime
WHERE
  t1.statusID=1
GROUP BY
  t1.ID, t1.logTime
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16f00/1).

Comment: Thanks for your reply...It removes the null column. But there is a chance where a Id has only the Check in Time. In that case we have to show Check_out column as null.. Eg: check with the foll query                        CREATE TABLE Logs (
  ID int,
  statusID int,
  logTime DATETIME);

INSERT INTO Logs VALUES
(100238 , 1 ,  '2011-07-07 03:48:43.000'),
(100238 , 1 ,  '2011-07-07 09:07:57.000'),
(100238 , 1 ,  '2011-07-08 02:59:57.000'),
(100238 , 2 ,  '2011-07-08 03:00:00.000'),
(100238 , 1 ,  '2011-07-08 09:26:37.000'),
(100238 , 2 ,  '2011-07-08 14:03:05.000')

Comment: @Renuka ok i understand... you're right, it doesn't work correctly in this situation... let me think how to solve this